# Time-independent source and quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, time, noethers-theorem, s-matrix-theory

Can anyone explain the fundamental reason of why time-independent sources cannot emit or absorb energy. Does it have to do with time-translation symmetry and Noether's theorem?

I was studying the following model of scalar field theory $$ \mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2} \phi^{2}-g \rho(\vec{x}) \phi(x)$$ where $\rho(\vec{x})$ is time-independent source. As stated in Coleman's note, the vacuum-vacuum expectation value should be 1 i.e $$\langle 0|S| 0\rangle=1.$$ Can anyone explain why should it be? Is it related to my earlier question of source being time independent?

Comment: What is S here? The S matrix?

Comment: Could you also give link to Colman's note?

Comment: @AdolfoHolguin yes the S-matrix

Comment: @Nikita http://fafnir.phyast.pitt.edu/py3765/Coleman-QFT.pdf